# How can i use the a tag

Tags: php, html

I have some code and would like to add an hyperlink to each entry on my database

tried using the 'a' tag

```
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
  <td><a href='details.php'><?php echo $row['game_name']; ?></a></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['game_year']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['system']; ?></td>
  <td style="text-align: center; color:green"><?php echo $row['owned']; ?></td>
  <td style="text-align: center; color:blue"><?php echo $row['completed']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['media']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['launcher']; ?></td>
<tr>
```

would like to be able to link to a details page

Comment: Check the server logs, you must have some error there if server logging is enabled. If server logging is not enabled, then enable it.

Comment: What's the problem here? Is something not working with the given code?

Answer (score 0):

`<a href='details.php?gameID=<?=$row['id']?>'>`

And in your `details.php` page you could fetch your DB:

`$gameID = (int)$_GET['gameID']` and a bit more error handling

Comment: I have added this to line 3 and nothing shows on screen

Comment: which page? The only thing we did for now was pass the `gameID` value. From there you can use it to fetch your database again. or change it to `<a href='details.php?gameID=<?php echo $row['id']?>'>`

Comment: the code is from my list page it shows all the games well it should but now it doesn't

Comment: looks like your setup does not support `<?=$var?>` change line 3 to `<a href='details.php?gameID=<?php echo $row['id']?>'>`

Comment: still not printing the game name

Comment: On what page? You might be missing a > check the syntax